# How to group values in pandas dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to group columns based on values and assign the values to a new class.

[Please find the dataset screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBYnZ.png)

I want to group values based on following conditions:

- If the Input File name, Page Number, Font Class, Font Size, Left for two or more rows is same, then it belongs to Group 1. Also if the Input File name, Page Number, Font Class, Font Size is same for two or more rows and the row values in Left with the range of +-5 to other(see row number 2 in the above dataframe Left value is 713, above left values(rows 0,1) are 708), it is also Group 1.
- If the Input File name, Page Number, Font Class, Font Size, Top for two or more rows is same, then it belongs to Group 2. Also if the Input File name, Page Number, Font Class, Font Size is same for two or more rows and the row values in Top with the range of +-5 to other(see row 5, here Top value is 1085 which is 4 less to the previous two values in Top column), it is also Group 2.

I tried duplicating the column values and applied class corresponding to it, from which I can solve for all same case.

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['Input File Name','Page Number','Font Class','Font Size','Left'], keep=False),'Group'] = 'Group 1'
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['Input File Name','Page Number','Font Class','Font Size','Top'], keep=False),'Group'] = 'Group 3'
```

How can I group if Left/Top values is within the range of +- 5 to the others?

Comment: Please notice that the data sample you posted doesn't enable us to understand what values refer to each column.

Comment: Hi @Aryerez  I have provided the dataset screenshot for better understanding